# Use Macro to copy&paste based on changes in values to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So first here is what my source data looks like:
[SampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lqGZ.png)

Final output:
[Output for "AAM, PCM"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn7do.png)

For each branch code in column A, I want to copy and past those cells (not entire row) into another workbook and then save that workbook as the branch code name. **This code below works perfectly for copying and pasting into new sheets within the same workbook but I can't seem to modify it to suit my needs. They use "resize" as a pasting method, which I am unfamiliar with**

```
Sub columntosheets()

Const sname As String = "Sheet1" 'change to whatever starting sheet
Const s As String = "A" 'change to whatever criterion column

Dim d As Object, a, cc&
Dim p&, i&, rws&, cls&
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With Sheets(sname)
    rws = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    cls = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    cc = .Columns(s).Column
End With
For Each sh In Worksheets
    d(sh.Name) = 1
Next sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(sname))
Sheets(sname).Cells(1).Resize(rws, cls).Copy .Cells(1)
.Cells(1).Resize(rws, cls).Sort .Cells(cc), 2, Header:=xlYes
a = .Cells(cc).Resize(rws + 1, 1)
p = 2
For i = 2 To rws + 1
    If a(i, 1) <> a(p, 1) Then
        If d(a(p, 1)) <> 1 Then
            Sheets.Add.Name = Left(a(p, 1), 25)
            .Cells(1).Resize(, cls).Copy Cells(1)
            .Cells(p, 1).Resize(i - p, cls).Copy Cells(2, 1)
        End If
        p = i
    End If
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Sheets(sname).Activate

End Sub
```

I have tried a few other methods and can't seem to get anything to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Previous Code I have used to generate workbooks using a list of branch names and the SaveAs function

```
For Each cell In MyRange 
    cell.Copy ws1.Range("I2").PasteSpecial ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs 
    Filename:="C:\Users\34389\Documents\test" & Range("I2").Value 
Next cell
```

Comment: Good idea including the source data. What does your successful copy look like for the first branch code? You want one workbook for each unique branch code?

Comment: As I asked "What does your successful copy look like for the first branch code" You can probably create the code to open the template, correct? And you already know how to use SaveAs correct?

Comment: You show your source data. Show an image of your output workbook and what it should look like. Reading code that kind of does what you want it too isn't helpful for us envisioning what you actually want it to look like - and edit your question - don't add pertinent stuff to comments

Comment: OK sorry, I am obviously a rookie to posting things here...I have edited my question and hopefully that helps address the issues. Thanks!

Comment: That helps - now where's the code  to open the template . In place of `Sheets.Add.Name = Left(a(p, 1), 25)` use the Open template and SaveAs code - then PasteSpecial - I only see copy in your original code not paste

Comment: So that's why I am struggling with this...I haven't used this method before, but the person who I originally got this from is using "resize" as a paste function. Because this is written in such a foreign way to me (my code is simplistic and clunky), I am struggling to edit it for my needs.

Comment: Okay - I don't know if I can look at it today but thanks for updating the question. Someone else might help in the meantime